# flatten nested dictionary into dataframe with uneven nests and lists

Tags: python, json, dictionary, nested

I have a particular nested dictionary that I can not figure out how to flatten into a dataframe. It involves creating columns for each of the 5 values of both the "d" and "p" dicts, as well as applying "$oid" and "gi" to both of the dicts within the "d" dict.

```
test = json.loads(j)
test
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bab"
    },
    "d": [
        {
            "d": [
                17317,
                16556,
                9680,
                55982,
                45948
            ],
            "h": 74.65,
            "ts": "2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00",
            "p": [
                61,
                76,
                137,
                152,
                122
            ],
            "si": "9829563c95d0155f",
            "t": 24.82,
            "ti": "0000000000000000"
        },
        {
            "d": [
                17821,
                17488,
                9199,
                56447,
                44089
            ],
            "h": 80.09,
            "ts": "2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00",
            "p": [
                61,
                76,
                137,
                152,
                122
            ],
            "si": "a42fbc88a44a316f",
            "t": 25.1,
            "ti": "0000000000000000"
        }
    ],
    "gi": "GW-P1007"
}
```

This is the format I am trying to obtain:

```
_id$oid, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, h, ts, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, si, t, ti, gi
5babf3dab512dd0165efd36c, 17317, 16556, 9680,55982,45948, 74.65,2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00, 61,76, 137, 152, 122, 9829563c95d0155f, 24.82, 0000000000000000
```

However, json_normalize() does not flatten the outer 'd' dictionary and puts everything in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're wanting to deal with `$oid` and `gi`. I'm assuming it will be the same for the columns, so you may need to adjust this. You may need to adjust the part to get the column names the way you want, but it more or less gives you what you need.

But what I did was flatten out the whole dictionary into 1 row dataframe, then iterate through the columns to create the separate rows.

```
test =[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bab"
    },
    "d": [
        {
            "d": [
                17317,
                16556,
                9680,
                55982,
                45948
            ],
            "h": 74.65,
            "ts": "2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00",
            "p": [
                61,
                76,
                137,
                152,
                122
            ],
            "si": "9829563c95d0155f",
            "t": 24.82,
            "ti": "0000000000000000"
        },
        {
            "d": [
                17821,
                17488,
                9199,
                56447,
                44089
            ],
            "h": 80.09,
            "ts": "2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00",
            "p": [
                61,
                76,
                137,
                152,
                122
            ],
            "si": "a42fbc88a44a316f",
            "t": 25.1,
            "ti": "0000000000000000"
        }
    ],
    "gi": "GW-P1007"
}]



import json
import pandas as pd
import re

jsonStr = json.dumps(test[0])


def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '_')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '_')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(y)
    return out

jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
flat = flatten_json(jsonObj)


results = pd.DataFrame()
special_cols = []

columns_list = list(flat.keys())
for item in columns_list:
    try:
        row_idx = re.findall(r'\_(\d+)\_', item )[0]
    except:
        special_cols.append(item)
        continue
    column = re.findall(r'\_\d+\_(.*)', item )[0]
    column = column.replace('_', '')

    row_idx = int(row_idx)
    value = flat[item]

    results.loc[row_idx, column] = value

for item in special_cols:
    results[item] = flat[item]
```

**Output:**

```
print (results.to_string())
        d0       d1      d2       d3       d4      h                         ts    p0    p1     p2     p3     p4                si      t                ti _id_$oid        gi
0  17317.0  16556.0  9680.0  55982.0  45948.0  74.65  2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00  61.0  76.0  137.0  152.0  122.0  9829563c95d0155f  24.82  0000000000000000     5bab  GW-P1007
1  17821.0  17488.0  9199.0  56447.0  44089.0  80.09  2018-09-26T21:02:19+00:00  61.0  76.0  137.0  152.0  122.0  a42fbc88a44a316f  25.10  0000000000000000     5bab  GW-P1007
```

Comment: thanks @chitown88. the original data is much larger than the example, and but it keeps the same nested structure. I am having trouble modifying the code to work on more data. I think it involves looping thru `jsonStr = json.dumps(test[0])` and then calling `for loop for items in columns_list`from within but i havent been able to get it to work. Do you have any ideas?